# Skip artifactory upload in jfrog if already exixts in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: artifactory, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jfrog-cli

In my build,I am doing upload of artifacts to JFROG in a stage of jenkins pipeline. If the target path is not present it will create the path and upload the artifact to the target. When I tried to upload the same artifact again, build is getting failed at that stage since it is already present on the target. I don't want to overwrite the artifact, instead I want to skip this upload stage when the artifact is already present in the target and the build should get success. How to validate artifact exists already in target and skip the upload stage in Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Comment: Is it Maven or Gradle? Generic? What kind of build is it?

Comment: its a generic jenkins build

Comment: @indhujasenthil Did you find a solution to this?